# How to describe a melody? --in a question of simulated TOEIC

Tags: adjectives

Here is a question in simulated TOEIC.
Due to its __ melodies and upbeat rhythms, Taylor Swift's music has broad appeal.
(A)simple
(B)funny
(C)kind
(D)common
I chose B that isn't the answer. A is correct, the reason in the official analysis is "simple" can describe melodies. I don't think it's convincing for me. So how do native speakers think? Is there a definite answer to this question? And why?
Thank you first.

Comment: Can you tell us why you feel A is not the right answer? And also why do you think B *is* the right answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Funny" means "amusing", which seems unnatural when referring to music, unless it's "joke" music like "whaah whaah whaah WHAAAAH!" played on a trombone to accompany a clown's pratfall.

Perhaps the word "fun" would be closer to how you would describe a melody -- but "funny" does not seem right, especially in this context.

Comment: Thanks. I regarded "funny" as “interesting” before.lol.

Comment: It can also mean "suspect", "suspicious", "surprising", "unwelcome", "unexpected", and can have an ominous connotation. "There's something funny going on here" would usually be interpreted as "something untoward". There was a colloquial phrase from mid-20th century: "Funny ha-ha or funny pecu?" where "pecu" is short for "peculiar": in other words, "clarify whether by 'funny' you mean 'amusing' or 'odd'."

Answer (score 2):

Funny has two meanings:

1. Amusing, humorous,...
2. Strange or unusual, often implying unpleasant.

Neither meaning works here.

> Due to its humorous melodies and upbeat rhythms, Taylor Swift's music has broad appeal.
>
> Due to its unusual (Not in a positive way) melodies and upbeat rhythms, Taylor Swift's music has broad appeal.

I searched through the internet and found other common adjectives for music, like:

> (positive, strong, gay, emotional, simple) melodies and upbeat rhythms.

Comment: "gay" would now generally mean LGBTQ, and indeed TS has taken a positive stand on LGBTQ rights,  but I wouldn't describe her music as "gay".